# Account Association bug or feature?

Tags: support, user-accounts, association

I recently associated a couple of accounts. I was going to ask a question on meta.stackoverflow... All of a sudden I receive 100 points on meta, another 100 points on cooking.SE and another 100 points on money.SE ???

I can understand getting +100 on meta as a 'starter' bonus (there was a question/answer about that somewhere). But I cannot understand getting +100 on the other sites, there was no merit in it.

I could start creating any number of associations just to get my cooking.SE rep up, and I don't think that's the idea behind account association.

I think I put an I in every sentence here, so... what do you think about it?

Comment: I posted this question because I received +200 on two sites. I've tried to reproduce this, but haven't received any more points, so this is closed.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce this, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a bug; once you reach a reputation of 200 in a site, you get a bonus of 100 points in all the SE sites where you associated the same account, and in all the SE sites you will join.

The bonus is given only once per each SE site.
If, for example, your account on Stack Overflow  reach the reputation of 200, you get the bonus of 100 on Stack Overflow, and in all the SE sites where you have the same account. If then you add the same account on a new SE site, you get the bonus on the new site, but not on Stack Overflow, nor the other SE sites, for which you already got the bonus.
Also, the bonus doesn't depend from the number of sites where your reputation is at least 200; if your reputation reaches 200 in a second SE site, the bonus doesn't become 200.

Comment: So, what happens with karma inflation?

Comment: Today i associated my account with two SE sites and get 100 points only on those sites, not on my SO account for example...

Comment: @user164226 You get the bonus only once per each SE site.

Comment: Ok, once per SE sounds good.