# Account Association bug. I received +200 reputation

Tags: support, linked-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Account Association bug or feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96062/account-association-bug-or-feature)

[Related to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96062/account-association-bug-or-feature), I received +200 reputation on cooking.SE,on money.SE and on stackoverflow.com (on stackoverflow I had less than 200 rep) on the 19th of June, when I associated my account with meta.stackoverflow.SE and with askubuntu.SE

I see only +20 on the 19th, and I don't see an accumulated graph of my rep counter.
[image: +20 on the 19th]

Comment: Not sure what makes this "related" to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96062/account-association-bug-or-feature), rather than "I didn't get the answer I wanted there, so I posted it again".

Comment: I did get the answer to that question. But **I think** I got +200 on cooking. On the 19th I 'only' got +20 from user clicks.

Comment: Rather than "thinking", check your `/reputation` page, or the reputation tab in your profile. If you can show us a screenshot of that rep boost, then you might have something worth posting a new question about.

Comment: I've just found my rep graph. 1490 on June 18th, 1610 on June 20th. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already answered in the duplicate you posted:

> It's not a bug; once you reach a reputation of 200 in a site, you get a bonus of 100 points in all the SE sites where you associated the same account, and in all the SE sites you will join.

Thus when you pass the threshold, you now get the bonus automatically with no action required on your part. This is true for all users including you.

> Jun 19    automatically granted association bonus due to UserId = 11498 on Stack Overflow crossing the rep threshold while associated , Reputation +100

Comment: That means that I didn't get +200 rep, right? I think I went from 1400 to 1600, and saw a notification bar about it. But I may be mistaken.